# None type object has no attribute update

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, sprite

I'm Trying to make a game. Like in any other shooting game, the enemies are supposed to disappear when shot. Apparently, you can't kill surfaces, but you can kill sprites. So I'm trying to load my images as sprites, but I'm getting a weird error. I make the class, apply a variable to it, make a variable for `pygame.sprite.Group`, and add the class variable to the group. When I try to update the group, It says `"'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'"`. Here's the code for the class:

```
class Spawn(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,primaryx,primaryy):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        global directionM
        self.directionM=directionM
        x1=random.randint(100,400)
        y1=random.randint(100,400)
        self.x1=x1
        self.y1=y1
        self.primaryx=primaryx
        self.primaryy=primaryy
    def AIPrototype(self):
        minionup=pygame.image.load("Alien.png").convert_alpha()
        miniondown=pygame.image.load("Aliendown.png").convert_alpha()
        minionleft=pygame.image.load("Alienleft.png").convert_alpha()
        minionright=pygame.image.load("Alienright.png").convert_alpha()
        global x,y,posx,posy
        seperate=random.randint(1,1000)
        screen.blit(self.directionM,(self.primaryx,self.primaryy))
        if seperate==2:
            self.primaryx=x+100
        if seperate==20:
            self.primaryx=x-100
        if seperate==150:
            self.primaryy=y+100
        if seperate==200:
            self.primaryy=y-100
        self.x1=self.primaryx
        self.y1=self.primaryy
        if self.x1<x:
            xspeed1=1
            slopex1=x-self.x1
        if self.x1>x:
            xspeed1=-1
            slopex1=self.x1-x
        if self.y1<y:
            yspeed1=1
            slopey1=y-self.y1
        if self.y1>y:
            yspeed1=-1
            slopey1=self.y1-y       
    #
        hypo1=((slopex1**2)+(slopey1**2))**0.5
        speedmark1=hypo1/1
        speedy1=slopey1/speedmark1
        speedx1=slopex1/speedmark1
        movex1=speedx1
        movey1=speedy1
        if self.x1<=640 and self.x1>=0:
            if self.x1>x:
                self.x1+=xspeed1*movex1
                if self.x1<x:
                    xspeed1=0
        if self.y1<=480 and self.x1>=0:
            if self.y1>y:
                self.y1+=yspeed1*movey1
                if self.y1<y:
                    yspeed1=0
        if self.x1<=640 and self.x1>=0:
            if self.x1<x:
                self.x1+=xspeed1*movex1
                if self.x1>x:
                    xspeed1=0
        if self.y1<=480 and self.x1>=0:
            if self.y1<y:
                self.y1+=yspeed1*movey1
                if self.y1>y:
                    yspeed1=0
    #
        if self.x1>640:
            self.x1=640
        if self.x1<0:
            self.x1=0
        if self.y1>480:
            self.y1=480
        if self.y1<0:
            self.y1=0
        if self.y1>=posy-20 and self.y1<=posy+20 and self.x1>=x-20 and self.x1<=x+20:
            Spawn.kill()
        self.primaryx=self.x1
        self.primaryy=self.y1
```

And this is the game loop:

```
spritegroup=pygame.sprite.Group()
spawn=Spawn(600,200)
spritegroup=spritegroup.add(spawn)
clock = pygame.time.Clock() 
keepGoing = True        

try:
    while keepGoing:
        clock.tick(60) 
        screen.fill(THECOLORS['red'])
        char()#start
        x+1
        posxlist.append(x)
        posylist.append(y)
        spritegroup.update()
        pygame.display.flip()
```

I realize that my code is really messy and inefficient, and I'm really sorry about that. I'm completely new to using classes and sprites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spritegroup.add(spawn)` returns `None`. Don't assign that back to `spritegroup`, the operation altered the object *in place*.

In other words, do this instead:

```
spritegroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
spawn = Spawn(600,200)
spritegroup.add(spawn)
```

From the [`spritegroup.Group.add()` documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.add):

> *add Sprites to this Group*
>   `add(*sprites)` -> `None`

Comment: Thanks! My error is gone. I've run into another problem though. I was told that updating the group would call the class, and display the enemy, but its not happening.

Comment: @Qartx sorry, I don't know enough about pygame to help you further there.

Comment: Thanks for the help though. I'll just post another question for this.